# Normalize axes to have squared plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

Consider the following series

```
lift = {}
lift['correct']=[0.0, 10.0, 18.0, 34.0, 44.0, 58.0, 66.0, 76.0, 84.0, 86.0, 88.0, 92.0, 92.0, 94.0, 98.0, 98.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
lift['avg'] = [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 60.0, 65.0, 70.0, 75.0, 80.0, 85.0, 90.0, 95.0, 100.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.draw()

handles = []
handles.append(ax.plot(lift['correct'], 'r-', label='Percent Correct'))
handles.append(ax.plot(lift['avg'], 'b-', label='Average Case'))
ax.set_xlabel('Total Population (%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Respondents (%)')
ax.set_ylim([0, 100])

num_xticks = 20
xtick_step = 100/num_xticks
ax.set_xticks([int(v) for v in range(0,num_xticks+1)])
ax.set_xticklabels([int(v*xtick_step) for v in range(0,num_xticks+1)])
#question 1
#ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
#fig.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

#question 2
#num_yticks = 20
#ytick_step = 100/num_yticks
#ax.set_yticks([int(v) for v in range(0,num_yticks+1)])
#ax.set_yticklabels([int(v*ytick_step) for v in 
#   range(0,num_yticks+1)])
fig.legend(handles, labels=[h[0].get_label() for h in handles])
fig.show()
```

What I get is [image: this plot]

I would like to have 2 axes normalized so that the plot looked squared on both axes like this
[image]
I tried the Q1 commented lines and get 
[image: this]

Question 1. How can I get a squared axes correctly ?

Question 2. How can I space y axis with ticks similar to x axes, at interval let's say step 10 or step 5. I tried Q2 commented lines and get this
[image: Q2]

Question 3. `fig.legend(handles, labels=[h[0].get_label() for h in handles])` is not showing any legend !?

Question 4. Any alternative and simpler approach to achieve the desired result is welcomed. I followed online examples and feel that my current approach is not so intuitive, notably from the part of splitting into `fig` and `ax`

Answer (score 1):

When plotting x against y, don't forget to supply x.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lift = {}
lift['correct']=[0.0, 10.0, 18.0, 34.0, 44.0, 58.0, 66.0, 76.0, 84.0, 86.0, 88.0, 92.0, 92.0, 94.0, 98.0, 98.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
lift['avg'] = [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 60.0, 65.0, 70.0, 75.0, 80.0, 85.0, 90.0, 95.0, 100.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(lift['avg'], lift['correct'], 'r-', label='Percent Correct')
ax.plot(lift['avg'], lift['avg'],  'b-', label='Average Case')
ax.set_xlabel('Total Population (%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Respondents (%)')

ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. How to make the plot zone cut off at exactly 0, or 100 (so that value 100 will flatline the top of the plot), or both (as in my original plot), without margin at bottom left and top right ? How could we add finer ticks at 5 or 10 interval instead of 20, on both axes ? Also, `fig.legend(handles, labels=[h[0].get_label() for h in handles])` is wrong ?

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, any feedback ? Thanks